# Get selected TEXT from nb-select

Tags: angular, nebular

I've implemented a Nebular Select control on a Angular 9 screen...

```
<nb-select placeholder="Please select a location" class="uk-width-1-1" (selectedChange)="changeLocation($event)">
            <nb-option *ngFor="let adj of adjLocations" [value]="adj.id">
              {{adj.name}}
            </nb-option>             
          </nb-select>
```

When the selectedChange event fires I can only get the VALUE of the selected option, but I want to get the TEXT as well...

I can't find any answers on how to do this...certainly I am not the only person who ever wanted to get a selected text from a select list??  Any help is appreciated..and I can post more code samples if necessary, but there isn't a lot to go off of.  The source list is ID/Text based and the list renders without any issues.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

What you receive as $event in the changeLocation method is an object with the same type of the one you put as [value] in the nb-option (in your case a number)... Try to use the entire "adj" object as [value]:

```js
  <nb-select placeholder="Please select a location" class="uk-width-1-1" (selectedChange)="changeLocation($event)">
    <nb-option *ngFor="let adj of adjLocations" [value]="adj">
      {{adj.name}}
    </nb-option>             
  </nb-select>
```

And you should be able to use it in your changeLocation method

```js
 changeLocation(selected: [TYPE OF adj]): void {
   // do stuff 
 }
```

Comment: yea it's working for me

Answer (score 0):

Well this is quick fix, on the method changeLocation($event)

do this:

```
changeLocation($event){
    let selectedValue = adjLocations.find(location => location.id === $event.id );
}
```